# help in positioning flash file in a Page

Tags: html, css, templates

Hey all , **I want to put a flash file in the bottom of the page like this** [site](http://www.flvhosting.com/)

I used margin property  & Padding but it doesn't look well . 
**I need the code to put it in the bottom of the page** 
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting position to fixed in css should do the trick. give it a high z-index value to put it above everything else just in case.

```
#yourFlashDiv {position:fixed; bottom:0; left:20px; z-index:4;}
```

Answer (score 0):

the z-index property is the one you are looking for. Set it to a high value (10 should be enough.). That would make sure the object stays in front of everything else on the page.
Also, The position property can made "absolute" as well, if need be.